# Child component in React doesn't get updated?

Tags: reactjs

The user.entries state gets updated; however, it's not getting passed immediately to the child component, it only gets updated on the second button submit and it passes the first user.entries not the second one, though.

**App.js file:**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl:'',
      box:{},
      route:'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: ''
      }
    }
  }

onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL,this.state.input).then(response => {
      if (response){
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify(
            {id: this.state.user.id}
          )
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(count => {Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count})});
      }
      this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries} />           
        </div>
)
};
```

**Rank.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Rank = ({name, entries}) => {
    return(
        <div className='mv2'>
            <p className='f3 mv0 white'>
                {`Welcome back ${name}, your entries count is...`}
            </p>
            <p className='f1 mv0 b white'>
                {`#${entries}`}
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rank;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not re-rendering the component after you update since you are directly updating the object. You need to instead use `this.setState`

```js
fetch(...)
  .then(...)
  .then(count => {
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      user: {
        ...previousState.user,
        entries: count,
      }
    }));
  });
```

Along with updating the state, `this.setState` also triggers a re-render of the component which is required to see the updated state on the UI as soon as the state is updated.